# Can I reuse request objects?

Tags: c, mpi

While using multiple `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv`, should I re declare `MPI_Request` request, or just declare once and reuse the request object. If I have to re-declare can you answer with an example.

Comment: Please note that I assume C language and added the respective tag based on your function capitalization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse `MPI_Request` variables. Those variables are only handles and they do not need to be initialized for passing them to `MPI_Isend` or `MPI_Irecv` (they are only marked as OUT parameters for those functions). Of course they have to be valid when passing to any function that completes them like `MPI_Wait`. Those functions will also set the variables to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL` upon completion.

You can even go further, and use *persistent communication requests*. If you have requests in a loop that retain the same argument list across multiple calls. You can use `MPI_Send_init` etc. together with `MPI_Start`. This can have better performance. Note that with persistent requests, the completion functions (e.g. `MPI_Wait`) will only mark the request as inactive rather than setting the variable to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`.